# Is there a built in api to extract a pattern (as many times as possible) from a string?

Tags: ruby, regex, built-in

I'd like to extract a pattern from a string as many times as possible with ruby 2.1. `String#slice!` appears close, but it only extracts the first match. To work around this I've written the following, but it feels clunky:

```
string  = "ababab"
pattern = /a/
matches = []

# clunky
loop do
  m = string.slice!(pattern) || break
  matches << m
end

#=> matches == ["a", "a", "a"]
#=> string  == "bbb"
```

Now I could extend the `String` class with my own `#extract!` method, or create a helper object for this, but I feel like this a common enough case that I'm just missing part of the standard API or a more idiosyncratic way to do this.

Is there a shorter way to write this?

Comment: @hwnd scan leaves the original string intact.

Comment: `scan` followed by a `gsub` (or `gsub!`)?

Comment: @matt snap. put that in an answer.

Comment: How many matches for `string = 'aaaa'`, `pattern = /aa/`? 2 or 3?  The term `"extract"` is the reason for my uncertainty.

Comment: @CarySwoveland 2 matches. The first `'aa'` term is match and removed, then the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) followed by [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) should do what you want in two steps:

```
string  = "ababab"

matches = string.scan /a/   # => ['a', 'a', 'a']
string.gsub! /a/, ''        # => "bbb"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a block to `gsub`:

```
string  = "ababab"
pattern = /a/
matches = []

string.gsub!(pattern) { |s| matches << s ; '' }

string  #=> "bbb"
matches #=> ["a", "a", "a"]
```